# Does this async method using TaskCompletionSource make any sense?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'am trying to understand a piece of code that hasn't been written by myself. It's an async method for sending an email and should try up to 5 times to send a given mailmessage.

```
public Task<bool> SendMail(MailMessage mailMessage)
{
    bool success = false;

    int i = 0;
    int smtpRetryCount = 5;
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("myprovider.de");
    smtpClient.Port = 123;
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

    int smtpRetryWaitTime = 2000;

    while (i < smtpRetryCount + 1)
    {
        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
            success = true;
            Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS");
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception");
            Thread.Sleep(smtpRetryWaitTime);
            success = false;
        }

        i++;
    }

    // This is the part that I don't get, does it make any sense?
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    tsc.SetResult(success);
    return tsc.Task;
}
```

I'm wondering if this is really async and if so, in which way it implements async properties. For me it doesn't make much sense, especially the last 4 lines.

Comment: The whole method makes no sense since it's synchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done this way because you want your API to be potentially asynchronous, while the implementation decides either if it's actually asynchronous or synchronous.

For that matter, you can either use [`TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Task.FromResult<TResult>(TResult result)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Task.FromCanceled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.fromcanceled(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Task.FromException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.fromexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

### Why it's advised to go for this approach?

Usually you follow this approach/principle because you can easily make the same API to work asynchronously by swapping the implementation, while turning an already synchronous API into *asynchronous* one requires an intensive and long refactoring to make the change ever possible.

At the end of the day, you shouldn't find great differences implementing your APIs this way thanks to the wonders of *awaitables* and `async`-`await`